# Refreshing x:Static property bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

WPF in .NET 4.5 allows binding to static properties using `x:Static` markup. I'm using it to binding my labels to resource strings. My labels look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.SomeResourceString}" />
```

Application allows localization and user can choose display language from Settings dialog. All translations are in place. The only problem I'm facing is that there is no apparent way of "refreshing" these bindings.

WPF in .NET 4.5 listens to static version of `PropertyChanged` event, but there is no way for me to raise such an event because `Resources` class is auto-generated and is not extendable (no `partial`).

Reloading the application is of course one solution, but I don't want to do that. Interestingly, any labels that are not on screen right now (in a different Tab for example) get updated correctly. It is only the current screen that is not updating.

Comment: "Resources class is auto-generated and is not extendable (no partial)" - make it partial. you will have to restore `partial` in Designer file after each changing of rsources, but otherwise it will be fine

Comment: @ASh: Yeah, that's probably the unwanted solution I'll end up with it appears. Thanks for the input.